# Install Magento 1.9x with downloader.php

Tags: php, installation, magento-1.9

I wanted to install Magento 1.9x on my localhost (I am using XAMPP), but I get an alert with an undefined error. Here is what I did so far:

I went to https://magento.com/tech-resources/download and downloaded the archive with 1.9x which contains a file named downloader.php.

I copy it on the root of my local site aka magestore.com and then went to http://local.magestore.com/downloader.php.
The first steps were pretty smooth and everything was fine except the download step.

[image]

when I click continue I get an alert with an undefined error, like this:
[image]

If I choose the FTP method at Magento Connect Channel Protocol I get another alert saying Could not connect to connect20.magentocommerce.com. Try again (refresh page)

Help, please!

Comment: Did you verify all dependencies are met? What do your log files tell you? Hint: there are several to look for, apache error.log, Magento logs in var/logs and I believe there's a directory for exceptions.

Comment: there is a step before this, called validation that check php version, required extensions:

PHP version is right. Your version is 5.6.32
PHP Extension curl is loaded
PHP Extension dom is loaded
PHP Extension gd is loaded
PHP Extension hash is loaded
PHP Extension iconv is loaded
PHP Extension mcrypt is loaded
PHP Extension pcre is loaded
PHP Extension pdo is loaded
PHP Extension pdo_mysql is loaded
PHP Extension simplexml is loaded

Comment: So nothing in the logs?

Comment: there is no such thing as magento logs, as the files aren't downloaded. I only have that downloader.php exctracted from the downloaded archieve, from their website..

Comment: I'll look in apache logs, but don't think I'm gonna find something there

Comment: You're running this code on a server (xampp), there must be at least Apache logs, maybe they can point you in the right direction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185116/discussion-between-alex-suciu-and-kasper-agg).